# How to draw a new UIBezierPath for a CAShapeLayer as values of the CAKeyFrameAnimation key change

Tags: ios

Folks,

I successfully animate the `bounds.size` of a `CAShapeLayer` using

```
[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"]
```

(It makes the `CAShapeLayer` gradually bigger)

Now, I need to draw a circle inside the `CAShapeLayer` each time based on the current size of the `bounds.size` as animation progresses.

How can this be achieved? 
Thanks.

Here is a working code (for simplicity I changed the circle with a moving bar)
When anim1 and anim2 are running we want to make sure that 'height' in anim2 is in sync with the changing value of 'height' in anim1.

```
CAShapeLayer * myShapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
myShapeLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
myShapeLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60);
myShapeLayer.position = CGPointMake(35, 30);
[myShapeLayer setBorderWidth:1.0];
[myShapeLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
myShapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
myShapeLayer.lineWidth = 2;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:myShapeLayer];

NSMutableArray * boxsizes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)],
                            [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(50, 60)],
                            [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(50, 70)],
                            nil];

CAKeyframeAnimation * anim1;
anim1=[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];
anim1.values = boxsizes;
anim1.duration=10.0;

CGMutablePathRef pA = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint   (pA,NULL,myShapeLayer.bounds.origin.x,   10);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pA,NULL,myShapeLayer.bounds.origin.x+10,10);

CGMutablePathRef pB = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint   (pB,NULL,myShapeLayer.bounds.origin.x,   myShapeLayer.bounds.size.height);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pB,NULL,myShapeLayer.bounds.origin.x+10,myShapeLayer.bounds.size.height);


NSMutableArray * pathX = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             (__bridge id) pA,
                             (__bridge id) pB,
                             nil];

CAKeyframeAnimation * anim2;
anim2=[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
anim2.values = pathX;
anim2.duration=10.0;


CAAnimationGroup* group1 = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
group1.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:anim1,anim2, nil];
group1.duration = 10.0;

[myShapeLayer addAnimation:group1 forKey:@"Somekeyhere"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You perform a parallel animation on the `path`, and for each bounds key frame, you set a new path.

To make sure the size of the oval lines up with the sizes for your first animation, derive the path from the size used for the first animation. Here's a modified version of your code:

```
CAShapeLayer * myShapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
  myShapeLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
  myShapeLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60);
  myShapeLayer.position = CGPointMake(35, 30);
  [myShapeLayer setBorderWidth:1.0];
  [myShapeLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
  myShapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
  myShapeLayer.lineWidth = 2;
  [self.view.layer addSublayer:myShapeLayer];

  NSArray * boxsizes = @[
   [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)],
   [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(50, 60)],
   [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(50, 70)]
  ];

  CAKeyframeAnimation * anim1;
  anim1=[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];
  anim1.values = boxsizes;

  NSMutableArray *paths = [NSMutableArray array];

  for (NSValue *sizeValue in boxsizes) {
    CGSize size = [sizeValue CGSizeValue];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:(CGRect){.size = size}];
    [paths addObject:(id)path.CGPath];
  }

  CAKeyframeAnimation * anim2;
  anim2=[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
  anim2.values = paths;

  CAAnimationGroup* group1 = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
  group1.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:anim1,anim2, nil];
  group1.duration = 10.0;

  [myShapeLayer addAnimation:group1 forKey:@"Somekeyhere"];
```

You can see I'm using the sizes to derive the paths, so there are the same number of keyframe points and they all have the right size.

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: How do I 'set a new path' for 'each key frame' and access the value of the bounds.size of 'that key frame'? 
Is there some sort of event listener via which I can know in which 'key frame' I am?
Thanks for the response.

Comment: I assumed from the question you knew how to use a CAKeyFrameAnimation? can you include that code in the question so I know we're talking about the same thing?

Comment: I added the code to the description part of this inquiry. Thanks.

Comment: Right, that's pretty much what I suggested, so is your question now how to make two circular paths? Does your real animation only have two values for the key frames?

Comment: My question is: 
As anim1 and anim2 are progressing and anim1 is changing the height of the bounds parameter of the CAShapeLayer, How can we synchronize the two animations and make sure that anim2 is picking up the desired height when it becomes available via anim1. I hope my question is clear. Thanks.

Comment: OK, sorry for the delay - this wasn't a question I could answer properly on my phone!